# what happens if i rename a parent directory while file is being written by program

Tags: linux

I have a question.

I'm running a program on a LINUX machine. This program is writing output to the file 'output.txt' within the subfolder 'SUB' of the parent folder 'PARENT'

```
PARENT
   |________SUB
             |_________ output.txt
```

I accidentally renamed PARENT while output was writing...Namely, I did the following command

```
mv PARENT PARENT_NEW
```

So far my program hasn't crashed or anything. Does anyone know the repercussions of what I just did?

Comment: Depending on the program, I expect you moved the current file, but it is going to create a new file with the same name as the original one.  If the file is kept open the entire time I don't believe you can move it, but if it opens and closes the files then you may have two files.

Comment: I didn't move the current file explicitly..I moved/renamed the folder it was in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to UNIX, the fill will be present in the new location. Here is a simple experiment:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/test
$ cat > /tmp/test/abc.txt
hello
world

and again!
```

So while `cat` is still waiting for input, open a new terminal and rename the folder:

```
$ mv /tmp/test/ /tmp/test2
```

Now back to earlier terminal: ( press `Ctrl+D` to complete the input to `cat` )

```
$ ls /tmp/test/
ls: cannot access /tmp/test1/abc.txt: No such file or directory
$ ls /tmp/test2/
abc.txt
$ cat /tmp/test2/abc.txt 
hello
world

and again!
```

So basically, unless the file or directory is deleted completely, it will be present in the new location after the write is complete.

However, if process `B` deletes a file `f` while some other process `A` is still writing to that file, the file `f` will be available to process `A` because it holds an inode reference. But for rest of the processes including `B` it will not be accessible. Any other process can still access file `f` only if it can obtain a reference to inode via file descriptors from `/proc/<PID-of-A>/fd`.

Answer (score 4):

On Linux, as inherited from Unix, once a file on the local disk is open, the process has a handle to it. You may rename the parent directory, you may even delete the file. These operations don't trouble the process writing to the file as long as it does not close and reopen it.

Comment: I just tried this on Mac OS X, also a Unix descendant, renaming the folder mid-copy didn't cause any problems.

Comment: unfortunately i'm not sure if the program will close and reopen it. the program is PLINK, a genetic analysis tool. hopefully not. thanks for your help!

Comment: Well, if it closes and reopens the file, it will likely start throwing errors, because the parent directory it wants to use is no longer there. If it is still running, you may want to rename the parent back, if possible.

Answer (score 3):

The file is kept open by the program via a file descriptor, which is an unsigned integer that the kernel uses to access files. Your action should have no effect.

Comment: Ok thanks! hopefully it doesn't have an effect...will let you know what happens.